# mysql one row split into two rows

Tags: mysql

I have table like this

```
 ID  travelname  bemail mname temail tman_name
 1    a          xxx     aa    bbb     cccc
 2    b          ddd     bb    xxxx    ssss
```

I have a requirement like this

```
 travelname     email  name
  a              xxx   aa
  a              bbb  cccc
  b              ddd   bb
  b              xxxx  ssss
```

I tried union query.

Any one plz help to me.

Thanks.

Comment: An what is the problem with your union query? Show us the query.

Comment: what the problem with union?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `UNION`, you have to make sure both queries have same number of columns.

Second query doesn't really need to include names because it will use the first query names, but you include it for clear reading.

```
 SELECT travelname, 
        bemail as email, 
        mname as name
 FROM mytable

 UNION

 SELECT travelname, 
        temail as email, 
        tman_name as name
 FROM mytable
```

Comment: I think you probably want a UNION, but you might want a UNION ALL. I also think it's good to understand the difference. In scenarios that would produce identical resulting rows, do you want to show all those identical resulting rows (UNION ALL) or just show distinct resulting rows (UNION)? For example, let's say for a given row in the original table, bemail = temail and mname = tman_name.  If in this case, you'd want two rows to display in the result set with the same travelname, email, and name then you should do UNION ALL. If you only want one row to display you should do UNION.

Comment: @VKK You are right but to resume your comment, remember `UNION ` will remove duplicates and `UNION ALL` will keep duplicates. In this case if both are equal you wont have a way to see the difference.